# How to delete values in matrix which are out of range -200 +200

Tags: matlab

I am wondering how can I delete all rows in a matrix which are out of specific range? In a matrix I need to look in the column testing(:,5) and delete all values which are out of range -200 +200. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
testing = 200 * randn(1e4, 5);

badRows = testing(:, 5) < -200 | testing(:, 5) > 200;
testing(badRows, :) = [];
```

Comment: I like it, but you should do - and + sepparatedly, probably OPs ranges are variable ;)